# ng-show doesn't show the Div even when my Array length evaluates to Zero

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

`<div class="emptyMessage" ng-show="{{ToBuy.Items.length}}==0" > Everything is bought! {{ToBuy.Items.length}} </div>`

I wanted the above Div tag to not show when my ToBuy.Items array has some elements in it. The Div tag should appear only when there are no Items in ToBuy.Items array has no elements.

When I removed all elements from the array (Tobuy.Items), the expression simply shows ng-show="0==0" and the Div Tag doesn't show up on the web page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`ngShow` expects an expression, so you do not want to put curly braces in it. Try the following:

```
ng-show='ToBuy.Items.length == 0'
```

I'd recommend making this expression a property on your controller instead of checking `ToBuy.Items.length == 0`. Business logic belongs in the controller, not in the view.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Good point on the controller in business logic

Answer (score 1):

Remove the expression inside the [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow),

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-show="ToBuy.Items==0"> Everything is bought! {{ToBuy.Items.length}} </div>   
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/26552/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ng-hide

```
ng-hide='ToBuy.Items.length'
```

or

```
ng-hide='ToBuy.Items'
```

both should work i think.